# Customize the CSS of lightning-helptext

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, ui, helptext

I am trying to customize the borders of the standard help text and using in a LWC component like below:

[image]

I would like the popup to look like a rectangle instead of the curved border.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this by updating `border-radius:0rem;` on the css class `.slds-popover` which is standard css class for helptext pop up.